# First order logic translation from the sentence "Nobody who loves every dog loves any armadillo."

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation, conjunctive-normal-form

i'm new to first order logic and i'm having some confusion with translating the sentence above.

My solution for the sentence is :

- ∀x ∀y ∀z ((DOG(y) ∧ LOVES(x, y) ∧ ARMADILLO(z)) → ¬LOVES(x, z)) (1)

But when i search on the Internet, there is a solution that says:

- ¬ ∃ x ((∀ y (DOG(y) → LOVES(x,y))) ∧ ∃ z (ARMADILLO(z) ∧ LOVES(x,z))) (2)

The conversion into CNF of (1) and (2) are different. Can anyone let me know which one is correct and give me a brief explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The second of these is correct. Observe that the first formulation is equivalent to $$\forall x\forall y\forall z(\neg Dog(y)\vee\neg Loves(x,y)\vee\neg Armadillo(z)\vee\neg Loves(x,z)).$$ The negation of which is $$\exists x\exists y\exists z(Dog(y)\wedge Loves(x,y)\wedge Armadillo(z)\wedge Loves(x,z));$$ that is, "there is a being, a dog, and an armadillo such that the being loves the dog and the armadillo." But this doesn't contradict the statement you were trying to formulate; we don't know that our being who loves this dog loves *all* dogs, and our statement is about beings who love *all* dogs.

If the situation you're trying to describe is not true, then someone both loves all dogs, and loves some armadillo. And the second formula is precisely the negation of this scenario.